# How to connect subdomain from a different provider to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

My client has a domain configured in a different provider and I built a website in AWS. We want to use their sub domain created in the different provider but the think is: they are using this domain to a different site as well, so they cannot set it via DNS server name; the second possibility would be via IP, however my IPs are not defined as I'm using Amplify to build the site.

Is there any other way we can connect their sub domain to my website?

Our two first options were: DNS server name but they are using te main domain to another site, so it would cause another issue and IP address but my IP are not defined as I'm using amplify to build.
I expect to be able to connect my website to their sub domain that is located in a different provider.

Answer (score 0):

In the Amplify console, go to *Domain management* under your app settings. From there, add your domain and make sure to exclude the root since you only want to set up a subdomain. You can view the required DNS records from there. Basically you will need to set up a CNAME on your DNS configuration.

This documentation might help - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-a-third-party-dns-provider.html

Comment: That doesn’t work well because it uses CNAME based on DNS, that means that the my third-party domain should be dedicated to this, however, my third-party domain is a sub domain, that means that I cannot set a DNS on my domain because it would cause failures.